# Restrict protocol extension to a single enum case

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to restrict `extension` to a `protocol` to a single `case` of `enum` only.

For example, this compiles:

```
extension FooProtocol where T == SomeEnum {}
```

But this doesn't:

```
extension FooProtocol where T == SomeEnum.CaseOne {}
```

I understand that this isn't possible since `case` in `enum` cannot be represented as a `type` by itself.

Is there a workaround to this?

Edit:

My case is something like the following:

```
extension SignalProducerType where E == AppError.NonError {
  func ignoreError() -> SignalProducer<T, NoError> {}
}
```

I wanted to expose `ignoreError` method only to those of which has an `ErrorType` as `AppError.NonError` (which is custom type)

Comment: Your first example does not compile. Perhaps you meant something like `extension FooProtocol where T == SomeEnum {}` as in your previous question? – I must admit that it is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve (perhaps because I don't know Scala :). `SomeEnum.CaseOne` is a possible *value* of the `SomeEnum` type, and not a type.

Comment: @MartinR A little typo there. I've edited the question to make my intention a little clearer!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve but in short not really. The type checker (and protocol conformance checking) happens at compile time and the case of the enum is generally only known at runtime.

You could define the method in the protocol extension to operate on the whole enum but return nil (or do nothing) for other cases.

Comment: I've edited the question to make intention clearer. Can you think of any alternative to such pattern?

Comment: I'm still pretty sure that you can't do that. Principally because you are the type system is compile time in general the compiler doesn't know the case of the enum. Instead define ignoreError to check the case and return nil if necessary.